# Background image color is changing in firefox only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I don't know if someone had this issue before but, let's review it quickly without any description..

In firefox *latest version*:
[image: in firefox _header_]

[image: in firefox _footer_]

Now, when I load the html inside chrome and/or internet explorer, here's how it shows:
[image: in chrome _header_]
[image: chrome_footer_]

You see the differences? Before judging: I split the background to 3 parts.. left side, mid side and right side.. and it's clear in the firefox images, but in chrome and in internet explorer latest version ofc, it shows perfectly!

Also, when I merge the images manually in Photoshop, I don't see that color changing thingy;

Is there any explanation why firefox changes my left/right side's colors and how to avoid it then?

Comment: Whaaat?! I don't believe this! Can you provide your code?

Comment: Ofc, but it will require that I upload the whole website! to view the images correctly;

Comment: Here's my CSS: 
http://pastebin.com/kKbTAZAi

Comment: Can you extract relevant parts from you code for this issue? You can try to create very simple html+css page from scratch with just those three images in the same placement as in original

Comment: Just created a new raw version of css that has no extra except for the background codes. and I tested it on the new html and it only showed the background thingy. and yet again, the same issue.. same firefox color change thing and perfectly on chrome/ie
http://pastebin.com/zjUUyhDQ

Comment: Can you show html code?

Comment: Uasing your latest css code i tryed to recreate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/s3zmbqd5/ Could not recreate it.

Comment: For obvious reasons, you do not have the image iteslf..
Maybe because I used png for the background and jpg for the inner sides?